# Searching for repeated entries in a 2d integer array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2d integer array which has 3 numbers in each index.

For example:

```
   examplearray=new int[][]
   {

        {0, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 1},

   };
```

I want to find out whether the first two numbers in each index match with the first 2 numbers at any other index.

In this example, `{0,0,0}` and `{0,0,1}` both have the same first two numbers. I'd like to create a code which can indicate this.

Comment: You may also want to check this one out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286028/finding-duplicate-int-in-2d-array

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to create a key class that represents the members of the outer array. The hackiest/fastest way is to use a long to stuff the first two numbers together:

```
Set<Long> keys = new HashSet<>();
for (int[] innerArray : examplearray) {
  long key = ((long) innerArray[0] << 32) | innerArray[1];
  if (keys.contains(key)) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(innerArray) + " has duplicate entries");
  }
  keys.add(key);
}
```

Comment: What a great solution!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this if you meant entries with the same first two digits as another entry

```
ArrayList<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>
for (int i = 0; i < examplearray.length; i++) {
  if (entries.indexOf( examplearray[i][0] + " " + examplearray[i][1] )) {
    // here is a duplicate
  } else {
    entries.add( examplearray[i][0] + " " + examplearray[i][1] );
  }
}
```

Comment: this works but it's O(n^2), you could get faster using a hash set but it's not "nice" to use string conversion when an alternative is available

Comment: its more readable than using a 32 bit shift and an or haha but its good to have both solutions for whatever application this may be for

Comment: I don't see how this is O(n^2)?

Comment: indexOf is linear time complexity

Comment: indexOf to check if the entry is already in the array is O(n)

Comment: ya like I said the shift is hacky but a faster solution than writing a key class (which I always think is better)